# Shuffle an array of strings randomly

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am writing a program that reads a text file as an input and randomly shuffles the array of strings for the user.
I have written a program that shuffles the string array randomly but I want to do it in a way that no two elements that are the same are beside each other.

Here's an example:
The original array would look like this

```
{1,2,3,4,5,1,2}
```

The shuffled array would look like this

```
{5,3,1,2,4,2,1}
```

But currently my program creates an output array of this

```
{5,1,1,3,2,4,2}
```

Here is my code that shuffles the elements randomly:

```
int i;  
char s[11][100];
char line[100], t[100];

/*Open the text file*/
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("players.txt", "r");

/*Read each line and put it into an element in an array.
Each line will be in a seperate element in the array.*/
i=0;
while(fgets(line, 100, fp)!= NULL){
    strcpy(s[i], line);
    i++;

}


/*Generates a random number stored in j and shuffles the order of the array randomly*/
for(i=1; i<10; i++){

    j = rand()%(i+1);
    strcpy(t, s[j]);
    strcpy(s[j], s[i]);
    strcpy(s[i], t);    

}
```

Comment: better use `std::random_shuffle` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle.

Comment: @Shravan40: That's not available in C, and even if it were, it doesn't implement the restriction OP is seeking.

Comment: How many duplicates are there in your set? Are there more than two duplicates for any given element?

Comment: @rici the program is originally written to randomly shuffle strings. There are 4  words, fighter, defender, Driver and watcher. Currently there is 3 fighters, 3 defenders 2 drivers and 2 watches. When the program randomly shuffles these strings sometimes a driver could be in the 0th element of the array and another driver in the 1st element of the array and sometimes a driver could also be in the 3rd element of the array if that makes sense.

Comment: OK. I did some analysis for the case where there are exactly two instances of each object here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35496042/1566221 but the strategy is the same. It's not really a duplicate, though.

Comment: To get a fair shuffle, you need to use a Fisher-Yates shuffle — which is what the duplicate question points you to.  You should be leery of alternatives; they can lead to uneven shuffling. See also [The danger of naïveté](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) for illustrations. See also [Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503). Note that you should consider whether the `rand()` function introduces a slight bias because `RAND_MAX` is not a multiple of the number of entries in the table being shuffled (it does; it might even be measurable).

Comment: @jonathan: i'm pretty sure OPs code *is* a F-Y shuffle, although I usually write it going in the other direction. But that's nit OPs question: the question is how to do a shuffke (presumably unbiased) where not all outcomes are permitted; specifically, those with two adjacent equal elements. F-Y (and the proposed dupe) does not address this restriction.

Comment: Bear in mind that your problem may be unsolvable: {"Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Doris"}  Whatever solution you come up with should be able to either recognise such an unsolvable problem, or time out after a set limit with a "Problem not solved" message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no better solution than repeatedly running the Fisher-Yates shuffle until you find an arrangement without adjacent duplicates. (That's usually called a rejection strategy.)

The amount of time this will take depends on the probability that a random shuffle has adjacent duplicates, which will be low if there are few duplicates and could be as much as 1.0 if more than half of the set is the same majority element. Since the rejection strategy never terminates if there is no possible qualifying arrangement, it could be worth the trouble to verify that a solution is possible, which means that there is no majority element. There's an O(n) algorithm for that, if necessary, but given the precise details you provided, it shouldn't be necessary (yet).

You can reject immediately rather than continuing to the end of the shuffle, which significantly cuts down on the cost of running the algorithm. So just use your shuffle algorithm, but restart the counter if you place an element beside one of its twins.

By the way, using `strcpy` to move elements around is really inefficient. Just shuffle the pointers.

Here's some code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496042/1566221). I've assumed that the duplicates are exact, for simplicity; perhaps you have some other way of telling (like looking only at the first word):

```
void shuffle(const char* names[], size_t n) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n;) {
    size_t j = i + rand() % (n - i);
    /* Reject this shuffle if the element we're about to place
     * is the same as the previous one
     */
    if (i > 0 && strcmp(names[j], names[i-1]) == 0)
      i = 0;
    else {
      /* Otherwise, place element i and move to the next one*/
      const char* t = names[i];
      names[i] = s[j];
      names[j] = t;
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
```

For your use case, where you have 10 objects with frequencies 3, 3, 2, and 2, there are 605,376 valid arrangements, out 3,628,800 (10!) total arrangements, so about five of every six shuffles will be rejected before you find a valid arrangement, on average. However, the early termination means that you will do less than six times as much work as a single shuffle; empirical results indicate that it takes about 33 swaps to produce a valid shuffle of 10 objects with the above frequencies.

**Note:** `rand()%k` is not a very good way to generate a uniform distribution of integers from 0 to k-1. You'll find lots of advice about that on this site.

Comment: thanks for your help and answer on this question, it helped a lot and the code seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ShuffleRand
{

```
static void randomize( int arr[], int n)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {

        int j = r.nextInt(i+1);

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     
     int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
     int n = arr.length;
     randomize (arr, n);
}
```

}

Comment: OP has tagged the question for `C`, not Java.

Comment: To be a good SO answer, it is important to explain the code you provide, and most importantly why it answers the question.